# Selector TabBackground often does not apply all the layer-lists' width as you select/deselect the TabItems in a TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have a `TabLayout` with a selector as its indicator background, like so:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/dashpageindicator"
    app:tabMinWidth="5dp"
    app:tabMaxWidth="15dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp">
```

The drawable `dashpageindicator` is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/indicator_dash_selected"
    android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/indicator_dash_unselected" />
</selector>
```

`indicator_dash_selected` and `indicator_dash_unselected` are `layer-list`s with differing width and height, like so:

`indicator_dash_selected`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:start="1dp" android:end="1dp">
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:thickness="2dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
        <size android:height="2dp" android:width="12dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/default_text_color"/>
        <padding android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

`indicator_dash_unselected`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:start="1dp" android:end="1dp">
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:thickness="2dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
        <size android:height="0.5dp" android:width="4dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/default_text_color"/>
        <padding android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I intend that when a particular `ViewPager` item is selected, the tab item is supposed to grow like so:

[image: Selected tab indicator (1) must be this big]

However, when I swipe to the other tabs, they *often* do not grow in `width`. Instead they:

[image: What actually happens]

All the attributes of the `layer-list`s work fine except for its `size`'s `width`

I say *often* because sometimes, it works perfectly. Second tab grows to the expected width and height if second tab is selected. Third tab grows if it's the one selected, and so on. But most often, no.

Also, whenever it works as it rarely does, I notice several seconds of delay. Meaning, the selected tab's background remains as `indicator_dash_unselected` for several seconds or minutes before becoming `indicator_dash_selected`

I also noticed that the `selector` works after waiting for a couple of seconds by:

1. Going to a new `Activity`
2. Going back to the `Activity` housing the
   `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`

Like so:

[image: How it's supposed to happen.]

**Nota bene:** `TabLayout` is in a `CoordinatorLayout` together with a `ViewPager` and a `ConstraintLayout` that `fitsSystemWindows`.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

**PROGRESS:** Acting on @Dhananjay's advice to put both `layer-list`s inside the `selector` `items`, this solution does not work either:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" >
        <layer-list>
            <item android:start="1dp" android:end="1dp">
                <shape
                    android:innerRadius="0dp"
                    android:shape="rectangle"
                    android:thickness="2dp"
                    android:useLevel="false">
                    <size android:height="2dp" android:width="12dp" />
                    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
                    <padding android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="false" >
        <layer-list>
            <item android:start="1dp" android:end="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
                <shape
                    android:innerRadius="0dp"
                    android:shape="rectangle"
                    android:thickness="1dp"
                    android:useLevel="false">
                    <size android:height="0.5dp" android:width="4dp" />
                    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
                    <padding android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this work-around.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < viewPager.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            View view = new View(this);
            tab.setCustomView(view);
            View v = (View) tab.getCustomView().getParent();
            if (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == i)
                v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 10));
            else
                v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 10));
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashpageindicator);
        }
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                changeTabDimen(tab, 150);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                changeTabDimen(tab, 50);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                changeTabDimen(tab, 150);
            }
        });

    }

    private void changeTabDimen(TabLayout.Tab tab, int i) {
        View view = new View(this);
        tab.setCustomView(view);
        View v = (View) tab.getCustomView().getParent();
        v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(i, 10));
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashpageindicator);
    }
```

Also modify your Tablayout

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/dashpageindicator"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"/>
```

Comment: Does not work, sadly. Again, everything else about `indicator_dash_selected` and `indicator_dash_unselected` works immediately except for the change in `width`.

Comment: Can you try putting the shape code directly into the selector xml? also change background color of one selector to check if they are changing on select deselect.

Comment: Just tried by putting the `layer-list`s directly inside the `selector`'s `items`. Doesn't work either. I even changed the `solid`'s color to a straight up hex value. I still have the same problem, @Dhananjay. :(

Comment: Is the color changing for selected tab? If you set a different color in indicator_dash_selected, say green. Is it changing for selected tab?

Comment: Color does not change when switching between selector items. Though each selector has the same color explicitly defined in them.

Comment: I have edited the answer try above code after setting your tablayout with viewpager.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169636/discussion-between-dhananjay-and-monica-labbao).

Comment: Hello @Dhananjay! Your solution works! --- for the most part. I'll post details later :)